# How do I read the association between Vehicle and Owner in this uml diagram?

Tags: associations, uml

Is this saying "A Vehicle is associated with 1 Owner" - OR - does it say "A vehicle is associated with many Owners"?

[image: UML Association]

Answer (score 3):

Exactly. The multiplicity and roles are located to the opposite of the class. So it's "a vehicle has one owner and an owner can have multiple vehicles".